# Blazor server: how do I prevent statehaschanged function from updating the UI on another browser (same web page opened)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm currently working on a blazor server project.

Initially, some of my front end components were not updating. Being new to blazor, i used observer pattern to notify the components but didn't work at first. I was able to resolve it by adding invokeasync with statehaschanged. Got the info from https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/pushing-ui-changes-from-blazor-server-to-browser-on-server-raised-events

However, when I used another browser (firefox) and opened the same page, the change in the browser(chrome) where the action is performed automatically updates the Firefox browser. How do I prevent that? I only would like the change to happen on the browser where the action is performed. I would like the other browsers to not update automatically and instead use the refresh (i am thinking of notifying the other browsers that a new data has arrived and they need to refresh, that could be my next step) . Is this possible?

When I removed statehaschanged, it didn't update the other browser, but it also didn't update some components on web page (which is my original problem that was resolved). I presume it does a signalR broadcast to all the other browsers that a change has occurred.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're working with?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a Singleton service for notification.   Everyone gets notified when when you trigger a notification.  Whatever your code looks like - no code so guessing in the dark - your notification/event service needs to be Scoped.   Code would help?

Comment: PS if `this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` helped and you're not using a timer (which is why it's called in the quoted article) then your basic component logic is probably not correct!